# Why isn't .forEach() working inside Array.prototype.fillB()? (a custom function)

Tags: javascript, prototype

I started experimenting with prototypes and I ran into a case that I don't understand.

I am trying to add a .fill(val) method to the Array prototype.

This code taken from another StackOverflow answer works:

```
Array.prototype.fillA = function(val) {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i] = val;
  }

  return this;
};
```

It looked like I could clean that up with a .forEach:

```
Array.prototype.fillB = function(val) {

  this.forEach(function(origVal, i, theArray) {
    theArray[i] = val;
  });

  return this;
};
```

But that doesn't work. (After .fillB is called, the array has not been changed).

So, what exactly is wrong with .fillB?

Here are some Runnable Snippets that demonstrate the problem:

#### .fillA()

```js
Array.prototype.fillA = function(val) {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i] = val;
  }

  return this;
};

var arr,
  output;

arr = new Array(5).fillA(5);

alert('arr = "' + arr.join(',') + '"');
```

#### .fillB()

```js
Array.prototype.fillB = function(val) {

  this.forEach(function(origVal, i, theArray) {
    theArray[i] = val;
  });

  return this;
};

var arr,
  output;

arr = new Array(5).fillB(5);

alert('arr = "' + arr.join(',') + '"');
```

*Disclaimers:*

- *I know that you should actually check that the .fill() function doesn't exist in the prototype before overriding it.*
- *Modifying a global prototype like this could have unintended consequences with other code libraries doing things like (for..in, etc), so it is usually a bad idea.*
- *.fillA and .fillB would actually do different things, i.e. .fillA only works properly on contiguous arrays starting at 0, but .fillB should work on all arrays.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an array with something like `Array(number)`, you are creating an array that only has the `length` property with the passed number, but it would not have any elements.

`forEach`, `map`, etc execute the function *for each element that actually exists*, ignoring the `length` property.

An array created with `Array(number)` is actually empty.

If you pass a several arguments to `Array`, it will create an array containing those arguments as elements.

So, if you use `Array.apply(0, Array.call(0, 5))` instead of `Array(5)`, you will create an array with 5 `undefined` elements.

**How it works**: `.apply` uses an array as arguments, and uses the length property to check the size.
So this line first creates an empty array with `Array.call(0, 5)` (you could just use `Array(5)`) and then, using the length property it looks for the 0,1,2,3,4,5 elements, and since they were never defined, the value of each one is `undefined`.

In another words, doing `Array.apply(0, Array.call(0, 5))` is the same as doing `Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined)`.

```js
Array.prototype.fillB = function(val) {

  this.forEach(function(origVal, i, theArray) {
    theArray[i] = val;
  });

  return this;
};

var arr,
  output;

arr = Array.apply(0, Array.call(0, 5)).fillB(5);

alert('arr = "' + arr.join(',') + '"');
```

Again, you could write `Array.apply(0, Array(5))`. (I don't, because jslint complains with that syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll give it a try in the morning.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> `forEach()` executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for indexes that have been deleted **or are undefined because no value was provided for them when the array was initialized.**

`new Array(5)` creates an array of length 5 (so `fillA()` works as expected), but with no values.